# Bootstrap collapse menu arrows at initial state

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap collapse to implement a vertical menu with submenus. I can toggle the visibility of the submenu content by clicking on a font awesome arrow icon. When the arrow is pointing down the submenu shows and when it is pointing up, it is hidden.

Everything is working fine, except when I want all my submenus to be expanded initially. The arrows are pointing down when they should be pointing up.

My code:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d45e7e578e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="mymenu nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item"> 
        <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#submenu1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1">
            <span>Menu Item</span>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse show" id="submenu1" aria-expanded="true">
            <ul class="flex-column nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">
                        <span>Submenu Item</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">
                        <span>Submenu Item</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> 
        <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#submenu2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu2">
            <span>Menu Item</span>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse show" id="submenu2" aria-expanded="true">
            <ul class="flex-column nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">
                        <span>Submenu Item</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">
                        <span>Submenu Item</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The css:

```
.nav-item{
    position:  relative;
}
.nav-link[data-toggle].collapsed:after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
    font-weight: 900; 
    content: "\f078"; 
    color:  #444444;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
.nav-link[data-toggle]:not(.collapsed):after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
    font-weight: 900; 
    content: "\f077"; 
    color:  #444444;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its Due to `collapsed` class, in the

```
<a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#submenu1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1">
        <span>Menu Item</span>
</a>
```

**Remove `collapsed` class**

```css
.nav-item{
    position:  relative;
}
.nav-link[data-toggle].collapsed:after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
    font-weight: 900; 
    content: "\f078"; 
    color:  #444444;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
.nav-link[data-toggle]:not(.collapsed):after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
    font-weight: 900; 
    content: "\f077"; 
    color:  #444444;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d45e7e578e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="mymenu nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item"> 
        <a class="nav-link " href="#submenu1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1" aria-expanded="true">
            <span>Menu Item</span>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse show" id="submenu1" aria-expanded="true">
            <ul class="flex-column nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">
                        <span>Submenu Item</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">
                        <span>Submenu Item</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> 
        <a class="nav-link " href="#submenu2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu2">
            <span>Menu Item</span>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse show" id="submenu2" aria-expanded="true">
            <ul class="flex-column nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">
                        <span>Submenu Item</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">
                        <span>Submenu Item</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why added both bootstrap 5 and 4 at the same time?

Comment: @praveenkumar I Just used the code given in the question. And in this case, there is no problem because version 5 CSS and version 4 js have been used. If we use both 5 and 4 versions of CSS was used there will be style override and repeation.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.cu-accordion-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--text-gray);
    outline: none;
    position: relative;  
}

.cu-accordion-item:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
.cu-btn-accordion {
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 }
.cu-btn-accordion:after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
    font-weight: 900; 
    content: "\f078";";
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    color: red;
}

.cu-btn-accordion:not(.collapsed):after {
    content: "\F077";
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d45e7e578e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="accordion" id="more-options">
   <div class="cu-accordion-item">
      <button id="btn-collapse-general" class="cu-btn-accordion
                            collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#box-collapse-general" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="box-collapse-general" type="button">
                            general
                        </button>
                        <div id="box-collapse-general" class="accordion-collapse
                            collapse" aria-labelledby="btn-collapse-general" data-bs-parent="#more-options">
                            <div class="accordion-body">
                               general
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cu-accordion-item">
                        <button id="btn-collapse-routes" class="cu-btn-accordion
                            collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#box-collapse-routes" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="box-collapse-routes">
                            routes
                        </button>
                        <div id="box-collapse-routes" class="accordion-collapse
                            collapse" aria-labelledby="btn-collapse-routes" data-bs-parent="#more-options">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                               routes
               </div>
          </div>
       </div>
                   
</div>
```