# What is the meaning of class collapsed in bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have noticed that while using accordions, the class "collapsed" is being used, not to be confused with the data-toggle="collapse". When I test what happens if I remove the collapsed class, well, the accordion works just as well even without the collapsed class issued to the buttons. For example you can look at the accordion example in the following link:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

```
<button class="btn btn-link collapsed"...
```

Can someone explain what is the class "collapsed" and what it does please?

I have noted the following question in SO, but there is no explanation on the collapsed class functionality.

[Bootstrap collapse menu arrows at initial state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68458090/bootstrap-collapse-menu-arrows-at-initial-state)

Comment: If nothing happens, maybe you are missing the javascript that would make the thing happen. Try to read again the very first sentence of the page you linked: `Toggle the visibility of content across your project with a few classes and our JavaScript plugins.`

Comment: It's not that nothing happens with the toggle itself, the buttons are working just fine and so does the accordion. Just it's working great even without the class collapsed. So I can remove the class, and everything works just the same.

Comment: As far as I know there is no `.collapsed` class in bootstrap.

Comment: Interesting question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reviewing Bootstrap v4.0 cdn, the `collapsed` class is only in the JavaScript file `bootstrap.min.js` and not present on any other file. Meaning it has no CSS style. It is used inside of loops and conditional statement and it does not matter if the user adds it or not, Bootstrap JavaScript will toggle that class supposedly to give the accordion the correct functionality, but I really don't see anything major related to that class, it may be something not having a real utility.